# tmux + emacsclient で elscreen-clone のようなことをしたい

Tags: emacs

tmux の中から、 `emacsclient -nw` を利用する形式で tmux と emacs を利用しています。

elscreen でいうところの、 elscreen-clone がやりたくなったのですが、これはどうやったら実現できますでしょうか。 (実現ができるのであるならば)
具体的にやりたいことは、「他の tmux window (別端末と読み替えても問題ない)で emacsclient を開く際に、既存の emacsclient の emacs window 配置をそっくりそのままコピーしたい」です。

自分の理解ですと、 各 `emacsclient -nw` は frame を作成しているので、新規の emacsclient (の frame) へ元の emacsclient の window 配置をコピーすればできるのでは、と踏んでいるのですが、これってそもそも実現可能だったでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は `window-state-get` と `window-state-put` を使う方法です。

```elisp
$ emacsclient -nw -e '
    (window-state-put
      (window-state-get (frame-root-window (nth 1 (frame-list)))))'
```

`(nth 1 (frame-list))` としていますので直前に作成した `frame` の `window configuration` が適用される事になります。また、`(nth 1 (reverse (frame-list)))` とすると、`emacsclient` で最初に作成した `frame` の `window configuration` が適用されます。

Answer (score 1):

@argus さんの回答を参考に、 emamux に、この機能の PR を作成、マージしてもらいました。

```
M-x emamux:clone-current-frame
```

で、 elscreen-clone のようなことができます。 emamux はMELPA からインストールできます。

Answer (score 0):

新しいフレームへの配置の複製とは異なる方法になりますが multi-tty 機能を使えばいいんではないかと思います。
http://lorentey.hu/project/emacs.html.hu

[image: multi-tty のスクリーンショット]

Comment: 確認なんですが、 multitty とは、別々の端末間で同一の emacs を利用する機能だと理解したのですが、それは emacsclient -nw での挙動によって呼び出されている機能そのものではないでしょうか。それとも何か自分はおもいちがいをしているでしょうか。